# как сохранить статус чекбокса при переходе на следующую страницу

Tags: java, jsf

Есть форма где список отфильтрованных пользователей, реализован чекбокс который по нажатию кнопки может выделять всех пользователей. При переходе на следующую страницу пользователей также можно выбрать всех и это выделение сохраниться.
Но если выделить поочередно т.е. самостоятельно несколько юзеров то при переходе на следующую  страницу чекбоксы слетают.
Как сделать чтобы чекбоксы сохранялись?

Comment: Чтобы чекбоксы сохранялись, надо их сохранять...  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   Скорее всего сейчас в модели запоминается только состояние чекбокса `selectAll`, нужно организовать ещё некий список выбранных пользователей/их идентификаторов.